# why in the shadow menu I only have a bias

Tags: lighting, shadows

![limited menu] When I click on my light then on shadow menu there is only have a bias. I am currently running blender 2.8 on windows 10 64 bit. Thank you in advance for all your help.

[image: only have a bias]

Comment: What is the question? what are you expecting to get?

Comment: The [shadow algorithm was updated/changed in 2.81](https://developer.blender.org/rBd8aaf25c23fa), which is why the *Softness*, *Exponent* and *Bleed Bias* have been removed, if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: I use Blender 2.81Thanks for the information